# Clear ant design autocomplete

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I have an Ant Design Autocomplete component in the header of my page (used for searching). I want to clear the text every time there is a route change. This is the code for the Autocomplete:

```
<AutoComplete
  dataSource={options}
  onSelect={this.onSelectOption}
  onSearch={this.search}
  labelInValue
  optionLabelProp="option"
  defaultActiveFirstOption={false}
>
  <Input
    ref={input => {
      this.searchBar = input;
    }}
    onPressEnter={e => this.goTo(e)}
  />
</AutoComplete>
```

I've tried using the `value` property of the autocomplete and setting it in state but nothing happens. Also tried setting the `value` in the child `Input` box but again nothing happens there either. Also tried doing `this.searchBar.value = "test";` but nothing.

Notes:
 - I'm using `ref` and and `Input` child component because I need to be able to set focus dynamically as well as call the `onPressEnter`

Comment: Reproducible example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. I assumed the Autocomplete value was a simple string but its actually an object with this structure:

```
{ key: '', label:'' }
```

Before when I tried to use the `value` property, I was setting a variable with `undefined` or blank string. So now instead, do this:

```
<AutoComplete
  dataSource={options}
  onSelect={this.onSelectOption}
  onSearch={this.search}
  labelInValue
  onFocus={() => this.setState({ focus: true })}
  onBlur={() => {
    this.setState({
      focus: false,
      searchInput: { key: undefined, label: undefined }
    });
  }}
  value={this.state.searchInput}
  onChange={e => this.setState({ searchInput: e })}
>
  <Input
    ref={input => {
      this.searchBar = input;
    }}
    onPressEnter={e => this.goTo(e)}
  />
</AutoComplete>
```